# Listing all ColdFusion & *Wildcard handler mappings in IIS 7

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I would like to list all of the handler mappings for all of the handlers for all of the websites configured in IIS 7. Or all of the *.cfm handlers for all of the websites, or all of the Wildcard handlers for all of the websites. Does anyone know how to do this? Also is there a way to find out which Coldfusion instance an IIS7 website is connected to other than looking at that website's handler mapping for * wildcard handlers?

Here is why, I have a Windows 2008 R2 server, IIS7, Coldfusion 9.0.2 configured in multi server mode. I have 3 Coldfusion instances running, there are about 50 websites configured in IIS7 on this server. The websites in IIS7 are configured to use one of the three CF instances. I thought website A was bound to CF instance A but when I brought down CF instance A, website A continued to work. I found website A was mapped to CF instance B.

The way I found this was by, in IIS7, going to the handler mappings of website A for *Wildcard handler to find it pointing to ...\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll. I then went into an IIS website that I knew was connected to CF instance A and looked at it's *Wildcard handler mapping which was pointing to ...\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll. To me,the fact that they were both pointing to wsconfig\1... told me they were both pointing to the same CF instance.

There has got to be an easier way to find this info out. If not does this info for all of the IIS websites reside in 1 xml file that a script can parse to get that info?

Thanks ~Joe~

Comment: It might just be me, but that wall of text seems pretty difficult to read - consider [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23566387/edit) to [add some formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). If it's easier to read it'll be more likely to receive a response.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this at Experts Exchange. The thread with what should be the answer can be found [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/Microsoft_IIS/Q_28430150.html#a40066244) where becraig listed some good powershell commands to get this information. For some unknown reason the get-website command is not working for me so I was unable to get the information I was looking for in my post.

I am going to uninstall powershell then reintall it in the hopes that I will get the commands that are not working for me.

Regards, Joe